# Migrating existing Java/Kotlin android app to React native app. But what todo with Existing sharedpreferences

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I have existing android app developed in kotlin/java. Now i want to create same functionality app in React-native but i am confused what to-do with existing shared preferences, Because react native asyc-storage is stored in RKStorage file and existing app's shared preferences. stored inside .xml file.

What can i do so when user update application they won't lose their existing data which is stored using shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing about react native prevents you from using shared preferences.  Find a library for it, or write your own module.  Then you can either just used shared preferences, or convert them on first boot.

Comment: Thanks but can you provide better lib/module you have used or you know. Ik i can create own module for this. But its better if you know any lib/module for this i have to take care in both os android as well ios.